# invalid int: "" in LogCat

Tags: android

I get a warning in LogCat that says invalid int: "". I traced the source down to the following code snippet:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
PagerAdapter pageAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

The last line seems to be the culprit. I don't know why but if I comment it, I don't get the error.

EDIT:

PagerAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

getFragments method

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fList.add(new Fragment1());
    fList.add(new Fragment2());
    return fList;
}
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: There is no stack trace

Comment: Can you post your `PagerAdapter` and your `List<Fragment>` please. And your Logcat will be helpful.

Comment: Added the code, there is nothing in LogCat besides the error.